# When i align a div to the center of a page using css it goes from the left side of the image not the center

Tags: css, html, alignment, center

This is the HTML

```
<div id="logo">
   <img src="image.png" 
</div>
```

and this is the CSS for it

```
#logo {
    position: absolute;
    display:block;
    /*background:#00FFCC;*/
    top: 5px;
    left:50%;
    max-width: 520px;
    max-height: 150px;
    min-height: 150px;
    min-width: 520px;
}
```

The image is aligned in the centre of the div but when I put 50% as the left attribute it uses the left side of the div as the centring point, so the left side of the div is in the centre not the middle, how can i change this?

Comment: does the logo div need to have position: absolute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To center the img in the logo do this

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/4JC3E/2/)**

```
img
{
    position: absolute;
    left:0;right:0;
    margin:auto;
}
```

or

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/4JC3E/3/)**

```
img
{
  display:block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use this instead (or margin-left):

```
margin:0 auto;
```